# Text Selector Cursor is Not disapeared After Switching the Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-cursor, textselection

I am building a android app in which there is a screen in which there are two tabs in form of fragment fragments are basically used for language translation. The problem is when i input something inside the the edit text of Multi Fragment and try to select it after i finished selecting if i suddenly move to the single fragment the cursor is still visible on single fragment for some duration ,Also the cursor is visible **ANYWHERE** in Single fragment screen.I'm not adding the code file because i think its not any logical problem its something related to **FOCUSED**.But if any one still need the code Please comment in question i will add that .

> Image 2 where currently cursor is visible that is a text view and its not clickable or editable

> > Image 1 Multi Screen

[image: input something inside the the Edit Text View]

> > Image 2 Single Screen

[image: Moving to the Single Fragment screen]

I try multiple Multiple things like
setFocusable(false);
clearFocus();
but its not working even I can

> > **isCursorVisible = false**  // this gonna work but after that I'm not able to select the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Long Scrolling the android documentation i find out the answer.

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    requireActivity().currentFocus?.clearFocus()  
}
```

Try to clear the current focus of your current view will sort this problem

Comment: I can also sort this by recreating my activity who is holding my fragment or by use of editText.isCursorVisible = false but these are not prefect as compare to **"by clearing the focus"**.